# PendingIntent sending the wrong intent / putExtra

Tags: java, android, android-appwidget

I am working on an appWidget and I got my first big problem.
I need to send to my app (CoreActivity) that the user click on image X or image Y (etc).
And what is exactly this image (in this exemple : Restaurant or Taxi).

My problem is : when the user click on an image, it always send the last putExtra (in this exemple Taxi). When I click on logo_1 or image1_1 it always send "Taxi" to my CoreActivity.

Do you know why ? Because I can't find anywhere what is wrong here...

Thanks for all the help you can bring me and thanks for the time you took (even for reading this question ^^).
Have a nice day.

```
final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_demo_4l_4c);

Intent logo_1Intent = new Intent(context, CoreActivity.class);
Intent image1_1Intent = new Intent(context, CoreActivity.class);
Intent image2_1Intent = new Intent(context, CoreActivity.class);

image1_1Intent.putExtra(CoreActivity.EXTRA_WIDGET_KEY, "Restaurant");
image2_1Intent.putExtra(CoreActivity.EXTRA_WIDGET_KEY, "Taxi");


PendingIntent logo_1PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, logo_1Intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent image1_1PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, image1_1Intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent image2_1PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, image2_1Intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.logo_1, logo_1PendingIntent);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.image1_1, image1_1PendingIntent);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.image2_1, image2_1PendingIntent);

appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
PendingIntent logo_1PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, logo_1Intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent image1_1PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 2, image1_1Intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent image2_1PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 3, image2_1Intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

You need to set different identifiers on each `PendingIntent`.